# How to use two seperate dataloaders together?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have two tensors of shape `(16384,3,224,224)` each. I need to multiply these two together. Obviously these two tensors are too big to fit in GPU ram. So I want to know, how should I go about this, divide them smaller batches using slicing or should I use two separate dataloaders?(I am confused, how to use two different dataloader together)
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @jonny-vu any suggestions?

Comment: You can't combine dataloaders but you can combine datasets (technically not true, but there are subtle issues when trying to iterate over two dataloaders at the same time). Do you have two separate datasets which have a 1-1 correspondence that each produce a (3, 224, 224) tensor upon invoking `__getitem__`?

Comment: For now, I just have these two tensors. What approach should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I totally understand the problem, but under the assumption that you have two big tensors `t1` and `t2` of shape `[16384, 3, 224, 224]` already loaded in RAM and want to perform element-wise multiplication then the easiest approach is

```
result = t1 * t2
```

---

Alternatively you could break these into smaller tensors and multiply them that way. There are lots of ways to do this.

One very PyTorch like way is to use a [TensorDataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset]) and operate on corresponding mini-batches of both tensors. If all you want to do is element-wise multiplication then the overhead of transferring tensors to and from the GPU is likely more expensive than the actual time saved during the computation. If you want to try it you can use something like this

```
import torch
from torch.utils import data

batch_size = 100
device = 'cuda:0'

dataset = data.TensorDataset(t1, t2)
dataloader = data.DataLoader(dataset, num_workers=1, batch_size=batch_size)

result = []
for d1, d2 in dataloader:
    d1, d2 = d1.to(device=device), d2.to(device=device)
    d12 = d1 * d2

    result.append(d12.cpu())

result = torch.cat(result, dim=0)
```

Or you could just do some slicing, which will probably be faster and more memory efficient since it avoids data copying on the CPU side.

```
import torch

batch_size = 100
device = 'cuda:0'

index = 0
result = []
while index < t1.shape[0]:
    d1 = t1[index:index + batch_size].to(device=device)
    d2 = t2[index:index + batch_size].to(device=device)
    d12 = d1 * d2

    result.append(d12.cpu())
    index += batch_size

result = torch.cat(result, dim=0)
```

Note that for both of these examples most of the time is spent copying data back to the CPU and concatenating the final results. Ideally, you would just do whatever you need to do with the `d12` batch within the loop and avoid ever sending the final multiplied result back to the CPU.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for exactly this answer. I'm new to deep learning, can you tell me more about when to use gpu and when to work on cpu alone with examples

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule but generally you have to consider the fact that whenever you're transferring data to/from the GPU then there's some, often times significant, overhead. In pytorch if you want to compute something like a sequence of complex operations on large tensors then transferring to the GPU usually results in a significant speedup (e.g. DCNNs). On the other hand, for something like an element-wise multiply the benefit of performing the computation on the GPU is likely overshadowed by the overhead of copying the data from RAM to GPU and back again.